# Navigate to last file in a folder on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

My folder on Google Docs drive has over 4000 files. How do I navigate QUICKLY to the end of the folder? Presently I have to scroll and scroll and scroll and I have never gotten to the end of the files within the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider organizing those 4000+ files into categorized folders. That would certainly ease navigation. As an alternative, clicking the Column name in the top of the Drive display which you would like to sort by changes the sort method(asc or desc), which would bring the last file *up* to you, as opposed to scrolling *down* to it.

Answer (score 1):

To quickly reach the bottom of the files list ,you can use the following short cut

Ctrl + End - this would take to the bottom of the file list

Ctrl + Home - This would take to the start of the file list

Comment: At this time Google Drive file lists having a lot of files are loaded partially. Ctrl + End will jump to the las file loaded and load more files after, so by repeating this operation it could take a while to jump to the last file in folder.

Answer (score 1):

Not quickly, but I have a folder with a similar amounts of files (backup of SMS, one file/message). I have written a simple Applescript that repeatedly sends End/PgDn. Then I go and do something while this script executes.

My use case was that I wanted to select all the files, and therefore needed to view them all. Otherwise I would have searched or changed sort order to find the files I was interested in. GMail has an option "select all messages, not just visible [that is limited to 100/page]". Can't understand why Drive doesn't offer something similar.

Answer (score 0):

On the column header of the files list on Google Drive, the sort order is shown by an arrow. Click on the arrow to invert the sort order so the last file will become the first file.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on a Desktop PC you may use the default shortcut Ctrl+Page down.

Could be a bit faster than scrolling.

Comment: This site is about using Web Apps :)